# Como mudar a localização do BackgroundImage em windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um objecto PictureBox que tem uma imagem definida e por tras eu coloquei um background mas eu não consigo mudar a posição do background

```
 pb.ImageLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\..\..\img\copovazio.png";
```

Eu queria fazer algo do tipo `pb.BackgroundImage.Location`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta imagem é composta por uma que faz o copo em transparente e uma textura azul que faz a água.
Queria mover essa textura debaixo para fazer a agua subir e descer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O controle da imagem é bem limitada, o que pesquisei que pode ser feito é sobrescrever o evento de desenho da imagem assim:

```
private void myButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, myButton.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Assim você poderá usar o TextAlign e Padding para poder contro-lar a movimentação da imagem.